# Connect to postgresql: FATAL: database "xxx" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to a local PostgreSQL database using Java, but gets `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "xxx" does not exist`

```java
public class TestDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxx","postgres", "Dlsdb@123");
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Database "xxx" exists. And in pgAdmin4 and `psql` it connected fine. I even used `python` and it worked fine:

```py
def test():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="xxx", user="postgres", password="Dlsdb@123", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
    print "Opened database successfully"
    conn.close()
```

I've updated `pg_hba.conf` and set it to this:

```
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32   trust
```

Tried `show ports` (if this helps), got `5432`

---

**UPDATE**

Tried some answers: changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` >>> not working.

And there's only one instance of postgreSQL(port 5432) is in listening...

btw I changed the db name `xxx` to `postgres` in my codes because that's a default db(I guess?) and it should exists anyhow, but got the same error...

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

See my comment below

Comment: Try to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1, like in python example.  However,  I doubt it will help :-) it's rather a desperate suggestion

Comment: @ygor I think `localhost` in the jdbc url is **the** problem

Comment: @ygor @alex, tried `127.0.0.1` in jdbc url, it's not working. Thanks guys \*_>\*

Comment: Find `postgresql.conf` and increase logging verbosity. You'll find your answer in the logs, hopefully.

Comment: @Mustafa Problem solved... I was running postgresql in a scala project and somehow the jdbc url was converted to an uppercase string... so it kept connecting database 'XXX' instead of  'xxx'. Noticed this in the logs, thanks a lot! XD

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java JDBC code to connect to an existing database (example PosrgresSQL 10.5). Make sure the the database is already created (use `psql` commands to verify, see below) and the driver is in the path (example driver: `postgresql-42.2.4.jar`).

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test_db?user=postgres&password=master";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Use `psql` *command line tool* to work with the database:

```
\list                   -- list all databases
\connect test_db        -- connect to a database
```

To drop and create the database:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test_db;
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
```

Comment: Can someone tell what is the issue with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

try to check if there is **only one instance** of PostgreSQL by using:

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 5432
```

Comment: Tried this, and there's only one result is in LISTENING: `TCP   0.0.0.0:5432   0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING`, others are `ESTABLISHED`